# Input to a paragraph no JS

Tags: html, css, input

How can I have a simple input form make changes the content of a p tag?

For an example

```
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
<p>Hi, NAME HERE</p>
```

I would also like to know how to change CSS with an input.

```
<input type="text" name="image"><br>
box{
  background-image: url("LINK FROM INPUT");
}
```

Comment: This isnt possible without js. Please post what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to do this purely with HTML and CSS, although you can add a pseudo-element `::before` or `::after` to add content directly before or after your paragraph tags. You would need JavaScript or jQuery to directly edit the element. You could also do this with PHP quite easily.

```
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
<p>Hi, $_POST['name']</p>
```

This assumes that the input is in a form with a submit button, and the form is submitting all the data with POST, or has `method="POST"` set.

There's no way to arbitrarily change your CSS file without something else going on as well. PHP would be required here; you could include the CSS for the `box` class on your page within `<style>` tags, and use a similar method as above.

Comment: Thanks for the help. =D